# Elastic Beanstalk + Nginx + Node + React 502 badegateway

Tags: node.js, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I have the following stack:

- node backend build
- react frontend build

I want to deploy them into an ELB application.

When I do that and try to access the instance I get **502 Bad Gateway nginx/1.18.0** instead of the home page.

The backend is up and running on port 8081 (made external request via postman and works properly)

The problem is with the static content.

Here's my code for **proxy.config** file (ebextensions for nginx)

````
  /etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf:
    owner: root
    group: root
    mode: "000644"
    content: |
        upstream nodejs {
            server 127.0.0.1:8081;
            keepalive 32;
        }

        server {
            root /var/app/current/react_build;
            listen 8080;

            if ($time_iso8601 ~ "^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})T(\d{2})") {
                set $year $1;
                set $month $2;
                set $day $3;
                set $hour $4;
            }
            access_log /var/log/nginx/healthd/application.log.$year-$month-$day-$hour healthd;
            access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

            location /api/ {
                proxy_pass  http://nodejs;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header     Connection      "";
                proxy_set_header     Host            $host;
                proxy_set_header     X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header     X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                client_max_body_size 10M;
            }

            location /static/ {
            }

            location / {
                try_files '' /index.html =404;
            }

            gzip on;
            gzip_comp_level 4;
            gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
        }

  /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/configdeploy/post/99_kill_default_nginx.sh:
    owner: root
    group: root
    mode: "000755"
    content: |
      #!/bin/bash -xe
      rm -f /etc/nginx/conf.d/00_elastic_beanstalk_proxy.conf
      service nginx stop 
      service nginx start

container_commands:
 removeconfig:
    command: "rm -f /tmp/deployment/config/#etc#nginx#conf.d#00_elastic_beanstalk_proxy.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/00_elastic_beanstalk_proxy.conf"```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `nginx` config file (`/etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf`) you are trying to set is for **Amazon Linux 1** (AL1).

For AL2, the `nginx` config files should be provided ([aws docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html)) using:

- `.platform/nginx/conf.d/`

or if you want to overwrite main `nginx` config file, use

- `.platform/nginx/nginx.conf`

Comment: @AlexMititelu No problem. Glad it worked out:-)